# One tab should open at a time and when click on another tab then it's tab should be foucs on tob

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I want to open one tab at a time and 
main issue is this: 
after we done one tab at a time:
When 1st tab open and we click on another tab then first content reduse his height and section tab title move to tob so user can not see the title i want then when i click on another tab then this tab focus on top of body screen.

After one tab at a time,  another tab tile move to top and that tile not visibal to user.

Can anyone help me on this point.

```js
// Multiple tabs starts //
  $(".tab-content").hide();
  $(".tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $(".tab-content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn("fast");

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("tab-active");
    $(this).addClass("tab-active");

    $(".tab-header").removeClass("m_tab_active");
    $(".tab-header[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("m_tab_active");

  });
  $(".tab-header").click(function() {

    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var m_tab_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#"+m_tab_activeTab).slideToggle();

    $(".tab-header").removeClass("m_tab_active");
    $(this).addClass("m_tab_active");
    $("ul.tabs li").toggle("tab-active");
    $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+m_tab_activeTab+"']").addClass("tab-active");
  });
  // Multiple tabs ends //
```

```css
.product-tabs-section {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*=============== tabs-module ===================*/
.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: calc(50% - 4px);
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul+.tab-header {
 border-top: none
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header>a {
 font-weight: normal
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: calc(20% - 4px);
 border-right: 4px solid #fff
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs>ul>li:last-child {
 border-right: none
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content h2,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .os-header__title {
 margin: 0 0 0.625rem
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-header.m_tab_active {
 background-color: transparent
}

.product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
 padding: 2.4375rem 8% 0.625rem;
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
 -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
 -moz-align-items: flex-start;
 -ms-align-items: flex-start;
 -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
 -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
 -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap
}

@media (min-width: 1199px) {
 .product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
  padding: 2.4375rem 8.9375rem 0.625rem
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
  padding: 0.5rem 2.8125rem 0.875rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .large-pra-style p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
 -webkit-flex: 0 1 50%;
 -moz-flex: 0 1 50%;
 -ms-flex: 0 1 50%;
 flex: 0 1 50%;
 max-width: 50%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  max-width: 100%
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step {
 margin: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description {
 margin: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description h2,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .os-header__title {
 margin-bottom: 0.75rem
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 margin-bottom: 1.0625rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner {
  padding-right: 8%
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video__image {
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: 90% center !important;
 background-color: #fff
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner.page-width {
 padding: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video__image {
 background-position: 100% center !important
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .feature-row__image-wrapper {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .feature-row__image-wrapper img {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0.9375rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
  margin-top: 1.5625rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium {
 height: 10.0625rem !important;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.875rem !important
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small.video-section-wrapper--min-height,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium.video-section-wrapper--min-height {
 height: 10.0625rem !important;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small.video-section-wrapper--min-height,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium.video-section-wrapper--min-height {
  height: 16.875rem !important
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content {
 top: 0;
 transform: none
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .page-width {
 padding: 0 1.875rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .page-width {
  padding: 0 1.25rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content h2,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .os-header__title {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 11.25rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content h2,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
 .checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .heading-1,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
 .checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .payment-due__price,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
 .checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .os-header__title {
  font-size: 1.625rem;
  line-height: 1.9375rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0 none
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video-control__play {
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 3.125rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper--with-text {
 margin-top: 0;
 height: auto
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper--with-text.video-control__play-wrapper {
 display: block
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper-mobile {
 display: none
}

.product-tabs-section .ratio-container:after {
 display: none
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div h6,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .checkbox__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkbox__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__previous-link,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__previous-link,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__description,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__price,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__price,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line__name,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .total-line__name,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table td,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div td,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table th,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div th,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__content,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__content,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .radio__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .radio__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .os-step__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .os-step__description,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__info,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__info,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column address,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div address,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column p,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .error-page p,
.error-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination .pagination__text,
.pagination .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination__text,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div h6,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .checkbox__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkbox__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__previous-link,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__previous-link,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__description,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__price,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__price,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line__name,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .total-line__name,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table td,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div td,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table th,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div th,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__content,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__content,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .radio__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .radio__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .os-step__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .os-step__description,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__info,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__info,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column address,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div address,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column p,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .error-page p,
.error-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination .pagination__text,
.pagination .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination__text {
 color: #000;
 font-family: "chaletnewyorknineteensixty", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 color: #666
}

.skinade-products-tab .feature-row__image-wrapper {
 margin: 0
}

.skinade-products-tab .feature-row__image-wrapper img {
 margin: 0 !important
}


.tabs-module .full-width-container {
 background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 3.125rem;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li>a {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 line-height: 3.125rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li.tab-active {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #f7f7f7
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li:nth-child(even) {
 border-left: 2px solid #fff
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li:nth-child(odd) {
 border-right: 2px solid #fff
}


 .tabs-module #page-tabs>ul {
  display: none
 }


.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content {
 padding-bottom: 2.1875rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content h2 {
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 0.625rem
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
 .tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content h2 {
  margin-top: 2.1875rem
 }
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .text-section p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 line-height: 1.125rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .text-section p.pra-heading {
 color: #000;
 font-family: "chaletnewyorknineteensixty", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 2px
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper {
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
 -moz-column-count: 4;
 column-count: 4;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
 -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
 column-gap: 1.25rem;
 orphans: 1;
 widows: 1
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
 .tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2
 }
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper .tab-content-inner {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1.125rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header {
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 3.125rem;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 line-height: 3.125rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border-top: 4px solid #fff
}


.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header.m_tab_active {
 background-color: #f0f0f0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shopify-section-skinade-product-tabs" class="shopify-section">
    <div class="product-tabs-section skinade-products-tab tabs-module top-spacing">
       <div class="full-width-container">
          <div id="page-tabs">
             <h1 class="tab-header m_tab_active" rel="tab1"><a href="#">what is skinade</a></h1>
             <div class="tab-1 tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: block;">
                <div class="page-width-small">
                   <div class="tab-content-inner" data-section-type="video-section">
                      <div class="text-section">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab2"><a href="#">the benifits</a></h1>
             <div class="tab-2 tab-content" id="tab2" style="display: none;">
                <div class="page-width-small">
                   <div class="tab-content-inner product-detail-last-step">
                      <div class="product-single__description rte">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab3"><a href="#">Ingredients</a></h1>
             <div class="tab-3 tab-content" id="tab3" style="display: none;">
                <div class="page-width-small ingredient-tab">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                </div>
             </div>
             <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab4"><a href="#">Nutrients</a></h1>
             <div class="tab-4 tab-content" id="tab4" style="display: none;">
                <div class="page-width-small nutrients-tab">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It 
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                </div>
             </div>
             <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab5"><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></h1>
             <div class="tab-5 tab-content" id="tab5" style="display: none;">
                <div class="page-width-small">
                   <div class="tab-content-inner">
                      <div class="text-section">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is you want..

Just append this part to `$(".tab-header").click()`:

```js
  var you_click_tab_header_top = this.offsetTop;
  setTimeout(function(){
    // sorry I'm unfamiliar to using jQuery, so I use pure js here.
    document.querySelector(".product-tabs-section").scrollTo({
      top: you_click_tab_header_top,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 400);  
  // jQuery fadeIn("fast") duration is 200ms, 
  // but sometime take over 200ms, 
  // So I kept an error value.
```

#### Result

```js
// Multiple tabs starts //
$(".tab-content").hide();
$(".tab-content:first").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function () {

  $(".tab-content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn("fast");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("tab-active");
  $(this).addClass("tab-active");

  $(".tab-header").removeClass("m_tab_active");
  $(".tab-header[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("m_tab_active");
});
$(".tab-header").click(function (e) {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var m_tab_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + m_tab_activeTab).slideToggle();

  $(".tab-header").removeClass("m_tab_active");
  $(this).addClass("m_tab_active");
  $("ul.tabs li").toggle("tab-active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + m_tab_activeTab + "']").addClass("tab-active");

  var you_click_tab_header_top = this.offsetTop;
  setTimeout(function () {
    // sorry I'm unfamiliar to using jQuery, so I use pure js here.
    document.querySelector(".product-tabs-section").scrollTo({
      top: you_click_tab_header_top,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 400);
  // jQuery fadeIn("fast") duration is 200ms, 
  // but sometime take over 200ms, 
  // So I kept some error value.
});
// Multiple tabs ends //
```

```css
.product-tabs-section {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*=============== tabs-module ===================*/
.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: calc(50% - 4px);
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul+.tab-header {
 border-top: none
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header>a {
 font-weight: normal
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: calc(20% - 4px);
 border-right: 4px solid #fff
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs>ul>li:last-child {
 border-right: none
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content h2,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-content .os-header__title {
 margin: 0 0 0.625rem
}

.product-tabs-section #page-tabs .tab-header.m_tab_active {
 background-color: transparent
}

.product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
 padding: 2.4375rem 8% 0.625rem;
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
 -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
 -moz-align-items: flex-start;
 -ms-align-items: flex-start;
 -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
 -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
 -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap
}

@media (min-width: 1199px) {
 .product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
  padding: 2.4375rem 8.9375rem 0.625rem
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .page-width-small {
  padding: 0.5rem 2.8125rem 0.875rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .large-pra-style p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
 -webkit-flex: 0 1 50%;
 -moz-flex: 0 1 50%;
 -ms-flex: 0 1 50%;
 flex: 0 1 50%;
 max-width: 50%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -moz-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  max-width: 100%
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step {
 margin: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description {
 margin: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description h2,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description .os-header__title {
 margin-bottom: 0.75rem
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner.product-detail-last-step .product-single__description p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 margin-bottom: 1.0625rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-content-inner {
  padding-right: 8%
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video__image {
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: 90% center !important;
 background-color: #fff
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner.page-width {
 padding: 0
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video__image {
 background-position: 100% center !important
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .feature-row__image-wrapper {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .feature-row__image-wrapper img {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0.9375rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner {
  margin-top: 1.5625rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium {
 height: 10.0625rem !important;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16.875rem !important
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small.video-section-wrapper--min-height,
.product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium.video-section-wrapper--min-height {
 height: 10.0625rem !important;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--small.video-section-wrapper--min-height,
 .product-tabs-section .tab-image-inner .video-section-wrapper--medium.video-section-wrapper--min-height {
  height: 16.875rem !important
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content {
 top: 0;
 transform: none
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .page-width {
 padding: 0 1.875rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .page-width {
  padding: 0 1.25rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video__text-content h2,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .heading-1,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
.checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .payment-due__price,
.product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .os-header__title {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 11.25rem
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content h2,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .heading-1,
 .checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .heading-1,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .sidebar .payment-due__price,
 .checkout-page .sidebar .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .payment-due__price,
 .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .checkout-page .os-header__title,
 .checkout-page .product-tabs-section .video__text-content .os-header__title {
  font-size: 1.625rem;
  line-height: 1.9375rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0 none
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
 .product-tabs-section .video-control__play {
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 3.125rem
 }
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper--with-text {
 margin-top: 0;
 height: auto
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper--with-text.video-control__play-wrapper {
 display: block
}

.product-tabs-section .video-control__play-wrapper-mobile {
 display: none
}

.product-tabs-section .ratio-container:after {
 display: none
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div h6,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .checkbox__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkbox__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__previous-link,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__previous-link,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__description,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__price,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__price,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line__name,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .total-line__name,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table td,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div td,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table th,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div th,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__content,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__content,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .radio__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .radio__label,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .os-step__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .os-step__description,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__info,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__info,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column address,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div address,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column p,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .error-page p,
.error-page .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination .pagination__text,
.pagination .product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination__text,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div h6,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .checkbox__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkbox__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__previous-link,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__previous-link,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__description,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .product__price,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .product__price,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line__name,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .total-line__name,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table td,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div td,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .total-line-table th,
.checkout-page .total-line-table .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div th,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .review-block__content,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .review-block__content,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .radio__label,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .radio__label,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .os-step__description,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .os-step__description,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .step__footer__info,
.checkout-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .step__footer__info,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column address,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div address,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .checkout-page .section__content__column p,
.checkout-page .section__content__column .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .error-page p,
.error-page .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination .pagination__text,
.pagination .product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div .pagination__text {
 color: #000;
 font-family: "chaletnewyorknineteensixty", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem
}

.product-tabs-section .nutrients-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p,
.product-tabs-section .ingredient-tab .tab-content-wrapper>div p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 line-height: 1.125rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 color: #666
}

.skinade-products-tab .feature-row__image-wrapper {
 margin: 0
}

.skinade-products-tab .feature-row__image-wrapper img {
 margin: 0 !important
}


.tabs-module .full-width-container {
 background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 3.125rem;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li>a {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 line-height: 3.125rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li.tab-active {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #f7f7f7
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li:nth-child(even) {
 border-left: 2px solid #fff
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs>ul>li:nth-child(odd) {
 border-right: 2px solid #fff
}


 .tabs-module #page-tabs>ul {
  display: none
 }


.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content {
 padding-bottom: 2.1875rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content h2 {
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 0.625rem
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
 .tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content h2 {
  margin-top: 2.1875rem
 }
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .text-section p {
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 line-height: 1.125rem;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .text-section p.pra-heading {
 color: #000;
 font-family: "chaletnewyorknineteensixty", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 2px
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper {
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
 -moz-column-count: 4;
 column-count: 4;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
 -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
 column-gap: 1.25rem;
 orphans: 1;
 widows: 1
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
 .tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2
 }
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-content .tab-content-wrapper .tab-content-inner {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1.125rem
}

.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header {
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 3.125rem;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 0.8125rem;
 color: #666;
 font-family: "chaletlondonnineteensixty", sans-serif;
 line-height: 3.125rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border-top: 4px solid #fff
}


.tabs-module #page-tabs .tab-header.m_tab_active {
 background-color: #f0f0f0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shopify-section-skinade-product-tabs" class="shopify-section">
    <div class="product-tabs-section skinade-products-tab tabs-module top-spacing">
        <div class="full-width-container">
            <div id="page-tabs">
                <h1 class="tab-header m_tab_active" rel="tab1"><a href="#">what is skinade</a></h1>
                <div class="tab-1 tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="page-width-small">
                        <div class="tab-content-inner" data-section-type="video-section">
                            <div class="text-section">
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
                                has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                                remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab2"><a href="#">the benifits</a></h1>
                <div class="tab-2 tab-content" id="tab2" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="page-width-small">
                        <div class="tab-content-inner product-detail-last-step">
                            <div class="product-single__description rte">
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
                                has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                                remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                                publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab3"><a href="#">Ingredients</a></h1>
                <div class="tab-3 tab-content" id="tab3" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="page-width-small ingredient-tab">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
                        Lorem Ipsum.

                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab4"><a href="#">Nutrients</a></h1>
                <div class="tab-4 tab-content" id="tab4" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="page-width-small nutrients-tab">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                        popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class="tab-header" rel="tab5"><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></h1>
                <div class="tab-5 tab-content" id="tab5" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="page-width-small">
                        <div class="tab-content-inner">
                            <div class="text-section">
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
                                has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                                survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we do this one tab open at a time, means if first tab open and if i click on another tab then opened tab should be close.